# Задача №2858. Лестница. Не проходит половину тестов

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Археологи раскопали Древний Храм, ко входу в который ведет лестница, шириной в 1 (один) метр, из М ступенек различной длины и высоты. Лестница построена из каменных блоков 1x1x1 метр. Археологи хотят для удобства туристов, чтобы лестница состояла из меньшего количества ступенек N. Для этого они могут также устанавливать каменные блоки 1x1x1. Какое минимальное количество блоков необходимо, чтобы сделать лестницу в N ступенек, если известны начальная длина и высота каждой ступеньки. Высоты и длины ступенек новой лестницы могут различаться.

**Входные данные**
В первой строке через пробел заданы два целых числа M и N (1 ≤ N < M ≤ 100). Далее идут M строк, содержащих пару целых чисел L и H - длина и высота i-ой ступеньки соответственно (1 ≤ L, H ≤ 101). Ступеньки нумеруются снизу вверх.

**Выходные данные**
В выходной файл выведите единственное число - ответ на задачу.

**Примеры**
**входные данные**

5 3

4 2

1 2

5 2

1 2

2 1

**выходные данные**

3

Вот мой код, набирает 54/100:

```
m, n = map(int, input().split())
l = [0] * m
h = [0] * m
res = list()
res.append(0)
f_n = m - n
for i in range(m):
    l[i], h[i] = map(int, input().split())

for i in range(f_n):
    s = 0
    min_s = 10 ** 10
    del_id = 0
    for j in range(m - 1):
        s = l[j] * h[j+1]
        if s <= min_s:
            min_s = s
            del_id = j
    res.append(res[-1] + min_s)
    l[del_id:del_id + 2] = [l[del_id] + l[del_id + 1]]
    h[del_id:del_id + 2] = [h[del_id] + h[del_id + 1]]
    m -= 1

print(res[-1])
```

Прошу найти ошибку или указать, как правильнее решать задачу. Писать код в ответ необязательно. Главное, пожалуйста, укажите ошибку :)
Сайт с тестами:
https://informatics.msk.ru (задача 2858).

Comment: А что за алгоритм применён? Он случайно не жадный?

Comment: @MBo, да, тут жадина применяется. Вычисляется площадь(т.е. количество блоков, которое нужно положить на i-тую ступеньку, чтобы она "слилась" со следующей. Так для каждой ступеньки. В итоге находится минимум, ступеньки сливаются, а лестница изменяется. И так m - n раз.

Comment: @MBo, есть идеи?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что динамическим программированием должно решаться быстрее, чем за квадрат, задача кажется сходной по структуре с 
"взять текущее или пропустить"

Comment: @MBo, ну там таймлимитов точно не будет. Возможно, нужно решать динамикой с двумя параметрами, где первый параметр - исходное количество ступенек, второй - то, что должно получиться. Хотя, идея не из лучших.

Comment: @MBo, можете разъяснить свою идею?

Comment: Во время нахождения минимума могут оказаться два и более ступеньки, для которых заполнение блоками является минимум, и в алгоритме могут слиться "не те ступеньки" и это не будет минимумом... Может из-за этого :/

Comment: А сами тесты доступны? Или хотя бы один тест, на котором ваша программа терпит неудачу? Ну или ссылку на саму задачу прямую дайте

Comment: Впрочем проблему понял, если у нас есть подряд 3 ступеньки 1х1, то слить среднюю будет невыгодно, да

Comment: Ребята, уравнение Беллмана. Читайте: М.Рейтман Лестница фараона http://kvant.mccme.ru/1991/10/dinamicheskoe_programmirovanie.htm

Comment: вы решили задачу?не могли бы вы поделиться решением)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многоуважаемый user342787, огромное спасибо за ответ:

> Ребята, уравнение Беллмана. Читайте: М.Рейтман Лестница фараона
>   kvant.mccme.ru/1991/10/dinamicheskoe_programmirovanie.htm –
>   user342787